# JPA 2 criteria API with @ElementCollection and like

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have the following entities

```
class A {
  @Id
  Integer id;

  String name;

  @ElementCollection
  @JoinTable(name = "othername", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_a"))
  @Column(name = "name")
  List<String> othernames;
}
```

I'm trying to use the criteria API to find instances of A using an infix search on the name or the other names. Basically something like this SQL-Query:

```
SELECT * FROM A
    WHERE name like '%something%'
    OR id IN (SELECT id_a FROM othername WHERE name LIKE '%something%');
```

The following code is meant to do the right thing:

```
String search = "%something%";
Subquery<Integer> subquery = c.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<A> subqueryFrom = subquery.from(A.class);
subquery.select(subqueryFrom.get(A_.id));
subquery.where(builder.like(subqueryFrom.get(A_.othernames), search));

query.where(builder.or(
    builder.like(from.get(A_.name), search),
    from.get(A_.id).in(subquery)
));
```

*I'm using a subquery here so I don't get duplicate results (e.g. someone searches for "a" and the name of an object contains "a" and the othernames contains an "a" as well).*

Now this code does not work, because subqueryFrom.get(A.othernames) returns an Expression<List<String>> while builder.like only accepts Expression<String>.

I actually think that my approach is completely wrong, but currently I can't think of any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a join for joining a collection relationship.  Use join(), instead of get().

Also, you don't need to use a sub-query, instead just put the join in the root query, and use a distinct.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#Join

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#CriteriaQuery